# Location of environment variables, where `_dupenv_s` function searches for the value?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, windows-ce, msdn

Where does the `_dupenv_s` function searches for environment variables for `varname` argument? If I wanted to change/add/remove environment variables the function look for where would I go?

Answer (score 0):

They are stored in the [`_environ`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stxk41x1.aspx) global variable. Use [`_putenv_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyw7eyfw.aspx) to add/modify/remove (empty "" string value to remove).

Windows processes also have a [separate environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682009(v=vs.85).aspx) that is used by the native Windows API functions.